# Git, WebDAV, and basic web hosting

Tags: git, http, web-hosting, webdav

I have a basic web hosting account through GoDaddy. It has plenty of space, and I was curious if I could use it as a push/pull/clone point.

I've read that Git supports HTTP(S) operations through WebDAV, but I've never used it. I'm not that familiar with WebDAV in general or how it works.

Is it possible to setup this sort of limited server to work with Git? I do not have SSH access on my account, but I do have permissions to config some basic .htaccess settings.

Comment: I think this depends on how much GoDaddy lets you configure things. To get git working with WebDAV, you have to do some configuration of DAV on the server (enable it, tell it about authorization). Here's a description of [how to do it with apache](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt); look at the "Step 2" section and see if that's configuration that GoDaddy will let you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two ways of hosting a git-repo on an http-server:

- "smart" HTTP, where you need a cgi-script installed on the server. This will probably not work for you, as basic web-hosting usually don't allow user-scripts.
- "dumb" HTTP, which is simply maintained by uploading the repo to the web-host. This would probably work for you.

"dumb" HTTP is a bit more awkward to use for the person who pushes to it, but it JustWorks(tm) for those who pulls from it. The pusher needs to run "git update-server-info" on the repo, and somehow get the repository over to the server (in the same way you'd usually upload files).

See the Git Book for details: http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly then, I won't be able to push to a remote "dumb" HTTP repo. I'd have to manually upload the new bare repo files. At that point I may as well zip up my repo, correct? No one will really be cloning this besides me.

Comment: If it's simply for your own purpose, perhaps something like putting a bare repo on Dropbox (or similar service) will suffice for you? I do that with my repos, and it works fairly well.